# Loop through each row

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am trying to run VBA code that generates email with doc attached.

The code generates only one email. I have 5 rows on my source Excel file.

I know I need a loop.

```vb
Sub Single_attachment()
    Dim appOutlook As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Source, mailto As String
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    mailto = mailto & Cells(2, 2) & ";"
    Source = "C:\Users\fk\Desktop\test invoices email\" & Cells(2, 3)
    Email.Attachments.Add Source
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    Email.Attachments.Add Source
    Email.To = mailto
    Email.Subject = "Important Sheets"
    Email.Body = "Greetings Everyone," & vbNewLine & "Please go through the Sheets." & vbNewLine & "Regards."
    Email.Display
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a for loop is the right way to go. Here's how to do that in your code:

```
Sub Single_attachment()

    Dim appOutlook As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Source, mailto As String
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'implement a loop that will set `i` each iteration, first to 2, then to 3, etc ending at i=6
    For i = 2 to 6
        'now when referring to a cell, use variable `i` for the row
        mailto = mailto & Cells(i, 2) & ";"
        Source = "C:\Users\fk\Desktop\test invoices email\" & Cells(i, 3)
        Email.Attachments.Add Source
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        Email.Attachments.Add Source
        Email.To = mailto
        Email.Subject = "Important Sheets"
        Email.Body = "Greetings Everyone," & vbNewLine & "Please go through the Sheets." & vbNewLine & "Regards."
        Email.Display
   Next i

End Sub
```